# Apache Olingo 4.2 API throwing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, apache, odata, olingo

I am trying to use apache Olingo 4.2 client API to access Microsoft CRM OData services which supports OData 4.0 . I am able to authentication api with Microsoft CRM by providing OAuth credentials , but while parsing the response EDMX document , API throws below Exception. It tries to match the parent URL with the reference URL which is different.

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

The referenced EDMX document has the URI http://vocabularies.odata.org/OData.Community.Keys.V1.xml where scheme, host, or port is different from the main metadata document URI 'https://crmonlinebcone.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.1

Please suggest on this , if someone faced same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue will be fixed in Olingo 4.4.0 release. See also: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OLINGO-1008